# How to navigate in a SPA inside an iFrame from an Angular application without reloading

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I have an IFrame in my Angular application. This IFrame links to a very big and slow SPA which takes a long time to load. For my purposes, I need to navigate inside this IFrame from my Angular Application.

i have tried changing the Url of the IFrame, but whenever the url is changed, it has to reload the entire application.

What I want to achieve is to be able to navigate inside my IFrame, from my angular application, just as if it was done by clicking a link in the SPA itself.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you expect to gain from changing the url of an iframe, without it loading the contents of that url?

Comment: I want to to load the contents of the new url, i just dont want to reload the entire SPA. Just like if I open directly that SPA in my browser, not in an IFrame, and let's say i'm on /users and then I click on a button that brings me to /users/123, it does not reload the entire application. So from my angular application, i wanna be able to tell my SPA inside the Iframe that is currently on /users to go to /users/123.

Comment: So the end result you want, is to change the page in the SPA without making it all load again, as if it was done by clicking a link in the application itself?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the intricacies of Angular, so there may well be a simple way to do that, but if it's a link that's on the page I'd just use Javascript to trigger a click event on it and let Angular do it's thing.  With my limited knowledge of Angular I'm struggling to see how else you could do it, since you're very clearly not within the $scope (being in a parent window).  I can assist you in clicking the link, if that's a viable solution, but otherwise I'd await an Angular guru.  I'd also recommend rewording the title & question.

Comment: Clicking the link is not a viable solution for us because we are planning on removing those links once we integrate the SPA with our angular application.

Comment: How about exposing a JavaScript function from the existing SPA that you can call from your parent to do the navigation instead? I think it will work if it's same origin